# Redirect an outbound call to an external sip (Watson)

Tags: twilio, ibm-watson

I'm trying to re direct an ongoing outbound call to an external sip (Watson assistant - phone integration), while it seems to connect, i can't hear anithing on the other side.
Even when trying to do the redirect with a normal phone number it seems to connect, but the other phone doesn't even ring.
This is the code i'm using:

```
client.calls
      .create({
         twiml:'<Response><Dial><Sip>sips:+<NUMBER_IN_TWILIO>@public.voip.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com</Sip></Dial></Response>',
         to: '<TARGET NUMBER>',
         from: '<SAME_NUMBER_IN_TWILIO>'
       })
      .then(call => console.log(call.sid))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

For redirecting to regular numbers i just use:

```
<Response><Dial><Number> "OTHER NUMBER" </Number></Dial></Response>
```

Any tip is greatly appreciated!
All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Saw this:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-interface

Note:
Twilio SIP Interface outbound call URI configurations using the sips URI scheme in order to enable end-to-end encryption is NOT supported by Twilio. However, we do support sip URI schemes using transport=tls for point-to-point encryption.

Also check your Twilio debugger for errors.

Comment: Thanks!
I think it is a bug on twillio's side, if you add a "<Say>" bafore the "<Dial>" it will work:
`'<Response><Say>Go!</Say><Dial><Sip>sips:+<NUMBER_IN_TWILIO>@public.voip.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com</Sip></Dial></Response>'`